# Integration procedure with real parameters

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The output of the following integration appear to produce imaginary terms, even though the parameters {a,b} have been specified to be real. My question: Is there a way to perform this integration where the imaginary "I" is absent.

```
Integrate[(1 + a*Abs[ze - zh])*E^(I*b*ze - a*Abs[ze - zh])*
  Cos[Pi*ze]^2*Cos[Pi*zh]^2, {ze, -2^(-1), 1/2}, {zh, (-1*1)/2, 1/2}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Reals]]
```

Some bits of the long output:

```
(* (4 E^(-a - (I b)/
   2) π^4 (7 a^11 b^5 + a^12 b^5 - 24 I a^10 b^6 - 3 I a^11 b^6 - 
    12 a^9 b^7 - 44 I a^8 b^8 - 8 I a^9 b^8 - 54 a^7 b^9 - 
    6 a^8 b^9 - 12 I a^6 b^10 - 6 I a^7 b^10 - 44 a^5 b^11 - 
    8 a^6 b^11 + 12 I a^4 b^12 - 9 a^3 b^13 - 3 a^4 b^13 + 
    4 I a^2 b^14 + I a^3 b^14 + 24 I a^16 E^a + 136 I a^14 b^2 E^a + 
    312 I a^12 b^4 E^a - 7 a^11 b^5 E^a + 336 I a^10 b^6 E^a + 
    12 a^9 b^7 E^a + 156 I a^8 b^8 E^a + 54 a^7 b^9 E^a + 
    12 I a^6 b^10 E^a + 44 a^5 b^11 E^a - 12 I a^4 b^12 E^a + 
    9 a^3 b^13 E^a - 4 I a^2 b^14 E^a - 24 I a^16 E^(a + I b) - 
    136 I a^14 b^2 E^(a + I b) - 312 I a^12 b^4 E^(a + I b) - 
    7 a^11 b^5 E^(a + I b) - 336 I a^10 b^6 E^(a + I b) + 
    12 a^9 b^7 E^(a + I b) - 156 I a^8 b^8 E^(a + I b) + 
    54 a^7 b^9 E^(a + I b) - 12 I a^6 b^10 E^(a + I b) + 
    44 a^5 b^11 E^(a + I b) + 12 I a^4 b^12 E^(a + I b) + 
    9 a^3 b^13 E^(a + I b) + 4 I a^2 b^14 E^(a + I b) + 
    7 a^11 b^5 E^(I b) + a^12 b^5 E^(I b) + 24 I a^10 b^6 E^(I b) + 
    3 I a^11 b^6 E^(I b) - 12 a^9 b^7 E^(I b) + 
    44 I a^8 b^8 E^(I b) + 8 I a^9 b^8 E^(I b) - 54 a^7 b^9 E^(I b) - 
    6 a^8 b^9 E^(I b) + 12 I a^6 b^10 E^(I b) + 
    6 I a^7 b^10 E^(I b) - 44 a^5 b^11 E^(I b) - 8 a^6 b^11 E^(I b) - 
    12 I a^4 b^12 E^(I b) - 9 a^3 b^13 E^(I b) - 3 a^4 b^13 E^(I b) - 
    4 I a^2 b^14 E^(I b) - I a^3 b^14 E^(I b) - 
    140 a^11 b^3 π^2 - 20 a^12 b^3 π^2 + 
    480 I a^10 b^4 π^2 + 60 I a^11 b^4 π^2 + 
    336 a^9 b^5 π^2 + 16 a^10 b^5 π^2 + 
    624 I a^8 b^6 π^2 + 120 I a^9 b^6 π^2 + 
    948 a^7 b^7 π^2 + 108 a^8 b^7 π^2 + 
    96 I a^6 b^8 π^2 + 84 I a^7 b^8 π^2 + 
    764 a^5 b^9 π^2 + 140 a^6 b^9 π^2 - 
    264 I a^4 b^10 π^2 - 12 I a^5 b^10 π^2 + 
    152 a^3 b^11 π^2 + 56 a^4 b^11 π^2 - 
    80 I a^2 b^12 π^2 - 32 I a^3 b^12 π^2 - 
    12 a b^13 π^2 - 12 a^2 b^13 π^2 + 8 I b^14 π^2 + 
    4 I a b^14 π^2 + 512 I a^14 E^a π^2 + 
    1776 I a^12 b^2 E^a π^2 + 140 a^11 b^3 E^a π^2 + 
    2688 I a^10 b^4 E^a π^2 - 336 a^9 b^5 E^a π^2 + 
    1920 I a^8 b^6 E^a π^2 - 948 a^7 b^7 E^a π^2 + 
    800 I a^6 b^8 E^a π^2 - 764 a^5 b^9 E^a π^2 + 
    264 I a^4 b^10 E^a π^2 - 152 a^3 b^11 E^a π^2 + 
    80 I a^2 b^12 E^a π^2 + 12 a b^13 E^a π^2 - 
    8 I b^14 E^a π^2 - 512 I a^14 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    1776 I a^12 b^2 E^(a + I b) π^2 + 
    140 a^11 b^3 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    2688 I a^10 b^4 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    336 a^9 b^5 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    1920 I a^8 b^6 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    948 a^7 b^7 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    800 I a^6 b^8 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    764 a^5 b^9 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    264 I a^4 b^10 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    152 a^3 b^11 E^(a + I b) π^2 - 
    80 I a^2 b^12 E^(a + I b) π^2 *)
```

Comment: You have a term `E^(I*b*ze...`. This is complex valued, so the integral is complex-valued.

Comment: @bill  The output for this integral is documented in the literature, and has no imaginary terms despite the occurrence of the term you pointed out....so perhaps is there another way of writing the code to avoid the imaginary output, any constraints that I can specify.

Comment: Could be that there's some cancellations that MMA isn't resolving by default. Try messing with the `Simplify` functions.

Comment: The output from your `Integrate` expression is a real-valued expression for a lot of real values of `a` and `b`, but not all. For example, neither `a` nor `b` can be zero.

Comment: Should this question be considered a duplicate of [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39968/3066)?

Comment: It is a close call, as this particular one deals with an explicit function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an expression that is `I`-free by evaluating

```
Integrate[
  (1 + a*Abs[ze - zh])*E^(I*b*ze - a*Abs[ze - zh])*Cos[Pi*ze]^2*Cos[Pi*zh]^2, 
  {ze, -1/2, 1/2}, {zh, -1/2, 1/2}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Reals]] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify
```

> ```
>  (8 E^-a π^4 (a b (b^4 - 20 b^2 π^2 + 64 π^4) (a^11 - 
>     7 a^10 (-1 + E^a) + 16 a^9 π^2 - 
>     4 a b^2 π^2 (b^2 - 4 π^2)^2 (3 b^2 - 4 π^2) - 
>     12 a^8 (-1 + E^a) (-b^2 + 8 π^2) - 
>     4 (-1 + E^a) (-3 b^2 + 4 π^2) (b^3 π - 
>        4 b π^3)^2 - 
>     6 a^7 (b^4 + 2 b^2 π^2 - 16 π^4) - 
>     6 a^6 (-1 + E^a) (-9 b^4 - 22 b^2 π^2 + 80 π^4) - 
>     4 a^5 (2 b^6 + 5 b^4 π^2 + 20 b^2 π^4 - 64 π^6) - 
>     4 a^4 (-1 + E^a) (-11 b^6 - 29 b^4 π^2 - 
>        116 b^2 π^4 + 256 π^6) - 
>     a^3 (3 b^8 + 4 b^6 π^2 + 64 b^4 π^4 + 
>        64 b^2 π^6 - 256 π^8) - 
>     a^2 (-1 + E^a) (-9 b^8 - 28 b^6 π^2 - 64 b^4 π^4 - 
>        448 b^2 π^6 + 768 π^8)) Cos[b/
>    2] + (24 a^16 E^a + 8 a^14 E^a (17 b^2 + 64 π^2) + 
>     4 a π^2 (b^2 - 16 π^2) (b^3 - 4 b π^2)^4 + 
>     8 (-1 + E^a) π^2 (-b^2 + 16 π^2) (b^3 - 
>        4 b π^2)^4 - 
>     4 a^2 b^2 (-1 + E^a) (b - 4 π) (b + 4 π) (b^2 - 
>        4 π^2)^2 (b^2 + 4 π^2) (b^4 + 16 π^4) - 
>     12 a^5 b^2 (b - 4 π) (b - 2 π) π^2 (b + 
>        2 π) (b + 4 π) (b^4 + 4 b^2 π^2 + 
>        32 π^4) - 
>     6 a^7 b^2 (b - 4 π) (b - 2 π) (b + 2 π) (b + 
>        4 π) (b^4 + 6 b^2 π^2 + 32 π^4) + 
>     24 a^12 E^a (13 b^4 + 74 b^2 π^2 + 192 π^4) - 
>     3 a^11 (b^6 - 20 b^4 π^2 + 64 b^2 π^4) + 
>     a^3 (b - 4 π) (b + 4 π) (b^3 - 4 b π^2)^2 (b^6 - 
>        8 b^4 π^2 + 64 b^2 π^4 + 64 π^6) - 
>     8 a^9 (b^8 - 15 b^6 π^2 - 36 b^4 π^4 + 
>        320 b^2 π^6) + 
>     8 a^10 (b^6 (-3 + 42 E^a) + 12 b^4 (5 + 28 E^a) π^2 + 
>        64 b^2 (-3 + 16 E^a) π^4 + 2816 E^a π^6) + 
>     4 a^8 (b^8 (-11 + 39 E^a) + 12 b^6 (13 + 40 E^a) π^2 + 
>        192 b^4 (3 + 13 E^a) π^4 + 
>        128 b^2 (-32 + 29 E^a) π^6 + 15872 E^a π^8) + 
>     4 a^6 (3 b^10 (-1 + E^a) + 8 b^8 (3 + 25 E^a) π^2 + 
>        96 b^6 (3 + 11 E^a) π^4 + 
>        192 b^4 (13 + 21 E^a) π^6 + 
>        2560 b^2 (-6 + E^a) π^8 + 24576 E^a π^10) + 
>     4 a^4 (-3 b^12 (-1 + E^a) + 66 b^10 (-1 + E^a) π^2 + 
>        32 b^8 (9 + 5 E^a) π^4 + 96 b^6 (-3 + 5 E^a) π^6 + 
>        1536 b^4 (4 + E^a) π^8 + 
>        1024 b^2 (-24 + 7 E^a) π^10 + 16384 E^a π^12)) Sin[
>    b/2]))/(a b (a^2 + b^2)^2 (a^2 + (b - 2 π)^2)^2 (a^2 + 
>  4 π^2)^2 (b^4 - 20 b^2 π^2 + 
>  64 π^4) (a^2 + (b + 2 π)^2)^2)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

The specific combination to use based on my comment is

```
FullSimplify[ExpToTrig[Integrate[(1 + a*Abs[ze - zh])*E^(I*b*ze - a*Abs[ze - zh])*
 Cos[Pi*ze]^2*Cos[Pi*zh]^2, {ze, -2^(-1), 1/2}, {zh, (-1*1)/2, 1/2}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[{a, b}, Reals]]]]
```

This will get you the real-valued result

```
(4 E^-a \[Pi]^4 (2 a b (b^4 - 20 b^2 \[Pi]^2 + 64 \[Pi]^4) (a^11 - 
    7 a^10 (-1 + E^a) + 16 a^9 \[Pi]^2 - 
    4 a b^2 \[Pi]^2 (b^2 - 4 \[Pi]^2)^2 (3 b^2 - 4 \[Pi]^2) - 
    12 a^8 (-1 + E^a) (-b^2 + 8 \[Pi]^2) - 
    4 (-1 + E^a) (-3 b^2 + 4 \[Pi]^2) (b^3 \[Pi] - 
       4 b \[Pi]^3)^2 - 
    6 a^7 (b^4 + 2 b^2 \[Pi]^2 - 16 \[Pi]^4) - 
    6 a^6 (-1 + E^a) (-9 b^4 - 22 b^2 \[Pi]^2 + 80 \[Pi]^4) - 
    4 a^5 (2 b^6 + 5 b^4 \[Pi]^2 + 20 b^2 \[Pi]^4 - 64 \[Pi]^6) - 
    4 a^4 (-1 + E^a) (-11 b^6 - 29 b^4 \[Pi]^2 - 
       116 b^2 \[Pi]^4 + 256 \[Pi]^6) - 
    a^3 (3 b^8 + 4 b^6 \[Pi]^2 + 64 b^4 \[Pi]^4 + 
       64 b^2 \[Pi]^6 - 256 \[Pi]^8) - 
    a^2 (-1 + E^a) (-9 b^8 - 28 b^6 \[Pi]^2 - 64 b^4 \[Pi]^4 - 
       448 b^2 \[Pi]^6 + 768 \[Pi]^8)) Cos[b/2] + 
 a (1 + E^a) (a^2 + 
    4 \[Pi]^2) ((a^2 + b^2)^2 (24 a^9 + 88 a^7 b^2 + 
       112 a^5 b^4 - 3 a^4 b^6 - 2 a^2 b^8 + b^10) + 
    4 (104 a^11 + 308 a^9 b^2 + 15 a^7 (32 + a) b^4 + 
       3 a^5 (108 + 11 a) b^6 + a^3 (112 + 29 a) b^8 + 
       3 a^2 b^10 - 8 b^12) \[Pi]^2 + 
    16 (184 a^9 - 12 (-9 + a) a^7 b^2 + 3 a^5 (96 + a) b^4 + 
       12 (1 - 2 a) a^3 b^6 - 17 a^2 b^8 + 22 b^10) \[Pi]^4 + 
    64 (168 a^7 - 4 a^5 (33 + 7 a) b^2 + 3 a^3 (40 + 7 a) b^4 + 
       21 a^2 b^6 - 28 b^8) \[Pi]^6 + 
    256 (20 a^2 - 17 b^2) (4 a^3 - a^2 b^2 - b^4) \[Pi]^8 + 
    4096 (4 a^3 - a^2 b^2 - b^4) \[Pi]^10) Sin[b/
   2] + (a^2 + b^2) (-1 + E^a) (a^2 + (b - 2 \[Pi])^2) (24 a^10 + 
    64 a^8 b^2 + 48 a^6 b^4 + 3 a^5 b^6 - a^2 (8 + a) b^8 + 
    4 (80 a^8 + 76 a^6 b^2 + 3 (12 - 5 a) a^4 b^4 + 
       9 a^2 (4 + a) b^6 - (4 + a) b^8) \[Pi]^2 + 
    32 (52 a^6 + 2 a^4 (14 + 3 a) b^2 - 12 a^2 (1 + a) b^4 + 
       3 (4 + a) b^6) \[Pi]^4 + 
    64 (4 a - 3 b) (4 a + 3 b) (4 a^2 + (4 + a) b^2) \[Pi]^6 + 
    1024 (4 a^2 + (4 + a) b^2) \[Pi]^8) (a^2 + (b + 
      2 \[Pi])^2) Sin[b/2]))/(a b (a^2 + b^2)^2 (a^2 + 
 4 \[Pi]^2)^2 (b^4 - 20 b^2 \[Pi]^2 + 
 64 \[Pi]^4) (a^4 + (b^2 - 4 \[Pi]^2)^2 + 
 2 a^2 (b^2 + 4 \[Pi]^2))^2)
```